# find object in iframe with jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe

this is not work... why??

from [http://api.jquery.com/contents/]

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>contents demo</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe src="http://api.jquery.com/" width="80%" height="600" id="frameDemo"></iframe>

<script>
$( "#frameDemo" ).contents().find( "a" ).css( "background-color", "#BADA55" );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and i tried like this

alert($( "#frameDemo" ).contents().find( ".constrain" ).html());

it's now work too...

please help me.

Comment: You don't have access to anything in that iframe due to the cross origin policy, as it's not on the same domain as your current page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the cross origin policy.

Question already answered here : [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

More information here : http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy

Comment: Thank you very much... I appreciate your answer